# asp.net c# ajax webmethod not fired

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

i have an ajax call using jquery like this :

```
$('#' + fupId).on('change', function (e) {
                readFile(this.files[0], function (e) {
                    //manipulate with result...
                    console.log(e.target.result);
                    var dataUrl = e.target.result;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Formulir.aspx/Upload",
                        data: '{ "dataUrl" : "' + dataUrl + '"}',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (msg) {
                            console.log("berhasil");
                        },
                        failure: function (msg) {
                            console.log(msg.d);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
```

readfile method :

```
function readFile(file, callback) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = callback
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

}
```

that js code will detect change on input type=file, and send data url to server side. this is Upload method :

```
[WebMethod]
public static void Upload(String dataUrl)
{
}
```

First time it work, when i input file. but when i try different size or greater size. that Upload method didnt fired.
this is my 15kb  file(fired) :

```
data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base…ludGVyU2V0dGluZ3MvcHJpbnRlclNldHRpbmdzMi5iaW5QSwUGAAAAABMAEwAaBQAAfDYAAAAA
```

this is my 259kb file(not fired) :

```
data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBlL0N…AvUHJldiAyNjEyODkvWFJlZlN0bSAyNjA2MjQ+Pg0Kc3RhcnR4cmVmDQoyNjQ3ODkNCiUlRU9G
```

please help me why this happend and how to solve this?

Comment: try to debug your code: firstly remove readfile method and check is it working.. or then using readfile.. place an alert above the ajax call. please let us know what is the result in these two conditions

Comment: if there is no readfile method, how i can get dataurl?